# display a text box inside my getStepContent method

Tags: html, css, reactjs, redux, material-ui

I am new to react and I am trying to learn react by using material-ui. I am trying to display a text box inside my getStepContent method. For each stepper I need to develop different ui, so I gave inside getStepContent method. But the problem is its displaying as html  and I dont see anty errors. Can you tell me how to fix it. Providing my code below.

https://codesandbox.io/s/2okwnkoonn

```
function getStepContent(step) {
  switch (step) {
    case 0:
      return `<TextField
                      id="standard-name"
                      label="Name"
                      className={classes.textField}
                      value={this.state.name}
                      onChange={this.handleChange('name')}
                      margin="normal"
                    />
                    For each ad campaign that you create, you can control how much
              you're willing to spend on clicks and conversions, which networks
              and geographical locations you want your ads to show on, and more.`;
    case 1:
      return "An ad group contains one or more ads which target a shared set of keywords.";
    case 2:
      return `Try out different ad text to see what brings in the most customers,
              and learn how to enhance your ads using features like ad extensions.
              If you run into any problems with your ads, find out how to tell if
              they're running and how to resolve approval issues.`;
    default:
      return "Unknown step";
  }
}
```

Comment: Although bullet-lists are nice for certain things, they should not be used as a question. It is harder to read the question this way.

Comment: @SølveTornøe hey I updated can you help me.

Comment: I have never used react, but the really quick google search could point at [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)
`<Typography dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: getStepContent(index)}}></Typography>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the parenthesis: *return **()***
AND you are trying to return a string rather than JSX.

Also, when you are working with text boxes in HTML and React, you want the text to be enclosed by the text box tags.

```
<TextField>sample text</TextField>
```

Here is your desired format:

```
function getStepContent(step) {
  switch (step) {
  case 0:
    return ( 
      <TextField
        id="standard-name"
        label="Name"
        className={classes.textField}
        value={this.state.name}
        onChange={this.handleChange('name')}
        margin="normal"
      >
            For each ad campaign that you create, you can control how much
      you're willing to spend on clicks and conversions, which networks
      and geographical locations you want your ads to show on, and more.
    </TextField>
  )
  case 1:
    return (
      <TextField
        id="standard-name"
        label="Name"
        className={classes.textField}
        value={this.state.name}
        onChange={this.handleChange('name')}
        margin="normal"
      > 
      An ad group contains one or more ads which target a shared set of keywords. 
      </TextField>
  )
  case 2:
    return (
      <TextField
        id="standard-name"
        label="Name"
        className={classes.textField}
        value={this.state.name}
        onChange={this.handleChange('name')}
        margin="normal"
      > 
      Try out different ad text to see what brings in the most customers,
          and learn how to enhance your ads using features like ad extensions.
          If you run into any problems with your ads, find out how to tell if
          they're running and how to resolve approval issues.
      </TextField>
    )
  default:
    return (
      <Text>Unknown step</Text>
    )
}
```

}

However, I do want to stress that if you want to return that long of a string, you should put them in a **constant variable!!**

Also, if you want to make your code even prettier, you can put the TextField Component into a separate const function and return it!

```
const EXAMPLE_STRING = "food"
```

Hope this helped!

### SYNTAX GUIDE

When you want to use the keyword ***this:***

**DO:**

```
class Example {
  example_function() {
    this.state ....
  }
}
```

**DON'T**

```
function example_function() {
  this.state ... // ERROR
}
class Example {...}
```

When you do not want to face ***NULL*** pointer exception:

**DO:**

```
class Example {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
      name: 'initialize'
      age: 0 // initialize
      friends: [] // initialize
    }
  }
  example_function() {
    console.log(this.state.name) // will not crash because it is initialized
  }
}
```

**DON'T**

```
class Example {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
      age: 0 // initialize
      friends: [] // initialize
    }
  }
  example_function() {
    console.log(this.state.name) // CRASH because attribute name does not exist!!!
  }
}
```

Comment: I updated in the sandbox but still not working...I am facing other errors, can you update it here https://codesandbox.io/s/1r3zvo18mj

Comment: The problem seems to be with your state code. You are calling this.state.name or other attributes multiple times; however, you never initialize "name" inside your state. Also, it is better practice if you put your function inside your class, so that you can call "this" component. Or else it can be undefined or crash.

Comment: The file is honestly way too long for me to go debug; but I will create a syntax guide you can follow in the answer above.

Comment: hey can you help me with this one too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53750902/passing-enter-key-event-completion-from-the-chip-component-to-the-tab-component

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a string. What you want to do is returning JSX. However, you also need to pass along your classes and your state as well, as you are using them in your returned value.

In short, instead of wrapping everything in backticks, you do something like this.

```js
function getStepContent(step) {
  switch (step) {
    case 0:
      return (
        <div>Step 0</div>
      );
    case 1:
      return (
        <div>Step 1</div>
      );
    case 2:
      return (
        <div>Step 2</div>
      );
    default:
      return (
        <div>Unknown step</div>
      );
  }
}
```

Don't forget, you also need to pass your function the state and classes as well, so you can use it like `{classes.textField}`.

Comment: hey can you help me with this one too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53750902/passing-enter-key-event-completion-from-the-chip-component-to-the-tab-component